# InDesign does not properly important Word paragraphs that are 3pt, it converts them all to 10 or 12 point. Why is this?

Tags: adobe-indesign, import

InDesign does not properly important Word paragraphs that are 3pt, it converts them all to 10 or 12 point.  Why is this?

Comment: Do you mean properly import? If yes, how are you importing the DOCX into InDesign? Are there styles applied to the text in Word?